# change navbar color with bootstrap

Tags: colors, navbar

Hi i want change navbar color in light orange.I use bootstrap.

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">`

My output is orange not light orange :(
I tryed also with CSS but don't work.
CSS:

```
<stryle>
.navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning{
        background-color:lightorange;
    }
</stryle>
```

i see on https://getbootstrap.com/ that there are only a few colors. How can change color of navabar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you tray that

```css
.navbar .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-light .bg-warning{
background-color:#000;}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
...............
</nav>
```